# How to generate control dependence graph for a C++ program

Tags: c++

I want to generate control dependence graph (CDG) for a C++ program.

I am wondering if there is any GCC/g++ debugging options that can help to generate this graph. For example, an option likes `-fdump-tree-cfg/cvg`, but for CDG (e.g. `-fdump-tree-cdg`). Or do you guys know any tool that can generate CDG for C++?

Comment: Doxygen can generate the diagrams and a lot more - I know you're looking for a way to do it from .cfg files, can't help you there though :)

Comment: Dump the idea unless you need to generate pile of worthless "documentation" to annoy someone to mad.

Comment: @MortenJensen: Thanks for your response. Can Doxygen generate CDG for C++ programs? I do not need to do it from .cfg files.

Comment: @user2197352 oh, I speed-read control dependence graphs as class dependence graphs :( control dependence graphs as in for static analysis, I think you'd need to look to Clang Static Analyser. Doxygen does none of that sort